# Set object in useEffect is not working in React

Tags: reactjs

I am new in React.I just want to show records in the table and I fetch data like

```
const [allowances, setAllowances] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("http://127.0.0.1:8000/allowances/")
      .then(data => {
        return data.json();
      })
      .then(data => {       
        setAllowances(data);      
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log("error",err);
      });
  }, []);
```

Here how I check length=>

```
<div>{allowances.length}</div>
```

if i log the data in before `setAllowances(data)` ,data has 3 records.But when I check `allowances.length`, there are no records. its show like `<div></div>`. So I think this `setAllowances` is not working.right? what is wrong?

Update

This is my data of i logged before setAllowance=>

[image]

Comment: Could you please show the contents of `data`?

Comment: @Mezbaメ Please check update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not setting the data correctly. As per the contents of `data`, it should be:

```
setAllowances(data.allowance);
```

Comment: wtf Thanks x 1000000.

Answer (score -1):

For `useEffect` hooks to update every single time that your state changes, you need to pass it as a parameter. This happens by passing `allowances` within the square brackets after you set your callback to `useEffect`. Check out [this](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#tip-optimizing-performance-by-skipping-effects) link

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I think this parameter is for something change right? Now my situation is for first times data binding.